# Mysql Trigger Or just a simple Insert statement .. which one is better to log history?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have so many tables in my DB.
eg. user, organisation,etc.

```
**User**

userId,name,age,orgId,etc..

**SessionLog**
logId, userId, operations, reason
```

If one admin makes changes like inserting, updating ,deleting, I will log every operations in SessionLog table **WHAT** he made.

So I plan to use Trigger.But the problem is I want to log the userId for **WHO** too. *By using Trigger WHAT is OK. **But for logging WHO, how can I do ?***

**1) do I need to retrieve the logId and need to update the row with WHO?**

or

**2) just use the simple INSERT statement to log everything? which way is better?**

**3) Is there any way to pass desired parameters to Trigger?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**1. User**

You can use CURRENT_USER to get this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user

**2. Insert statement vs. Trigger**

A trigger will abstract logging away from everybody else, and usually is the easiest solution that stays hidden.

INSERTS / UPDATES will not return until the trigger has completed.

Therefore while triggers on tables with light activity is an OK idea, it will become a real hindrance when dealing with tables that have a lot of activity.

Another option is to encapsulate this in the data access layer, but if you have even a single user that has direct access to the data (DBA included) then I do not recommend this approach.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I will learn and test current_user function.

Comment: As current_user only return as example: root@localhost. Not the desired LogIn userId of my own table. Anyway to Pass Parameter to Trigger?

Comment: @Grace: no, but you can use session variables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html